# Make an iPhone app designed for a 4-inch display compatible with 3.5 inches

Tags: ios, user-interface, screen, uistoryboard

My app was designed solely with a 4-inch display in mind. When run on a 3.5-inch simulator, there's .5 inches of the app missing.

My question, then, is how can I, in Xcode 5, set a different storyboard for a different screen size?

I know that before I could use the following piece of code:

```
-(void)initializeStoryBoardBasedOnScreenSize {

if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{    // The iOS device = iPhone or iPod Touch


    CGSize iOSDeviceScreenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

    if (iOSDeviceScreenSize.height == 480)
    {   // iPhone 3GS, 4, and 4S and iPod Touch 3rd and 4th generation: 3.5 inch screen (diagonally measured)

        // Instantiate a new storyboard object using the storyboard file named Storyboard_iPhone35
        UIStoryboard *Main_iPhone2 = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone3" bundle:nil];

        // Instantiate the initial view controller object from the storyboard
        UIViewController *initialViewController = [Main_iPhone2 instantiateInitialViewController];

        // Instantiate a UIWindow object and initialize it with the screen size of the iOS device
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

        // Set the initial view controller to be the root view controller of the window object
        self.window.rootViewController  = initialViewController;

        // Set the window object to be the key window and show it
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }

    if (iOSDeviceScreenSize.height == 568)
    {   // iPhone 5 and iPod Touch 5th generation: 4 inch screen (diagonally measured)

        // Instantiate a new storyboard object using the storyboard file named Storyboard_iPhone4
        UIStoryboard *Main_iPhone = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];

        // Instantiate the initial view controller object from the storyboard
        UIViewController *initialViewController = [Main_iPhone instantiateInitialViewController];

        // Instantiate a UIWindow object and initialize it with the screen size of the iOS device
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

        // Set the initial view controller to be the root view controller of the window object
        self.window.rootViewController  = initialViewController;

        // Set the window object to be the key window and show it
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }

} else if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)

{   // The iOS device = iPad

    UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
    splitViewController.delegate = (id)navigationController.topViewController;

}
```

}

But the deal with Xcode 5, and what I believe the reason this code isn't working is that there is a section in under "General" within your project that establishes a storyboard as the main one throughout the specific device type.

So, either there's a different way of doing the whole separate storyboard thing, or I'm doing something wrong with the code. That code was placed in my application delegate, so don't think I have anything wrong there.

Comment: Try autolayout, this will solve your problem..

Comment: I have it enabled. The thing is that since I developed the whole thing with the iPhone 5 screen dimensions in mind things can't downscale. I want to know if maybe i can establish two seperate storyboards for each screen dimension.

Comment: This is a common problem and many answers exist if you are willing to search for them.

Comment: @PatricioGuerra I am facing the same problem. Could you solve it?

Comment: @trojanfoe Could you let me know one such solution. I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Storyboard in Xcode 5 with autolayout enabled]

Find this control in Xcode 5 - Storyboard. The button all the way to the left switches between 3.5 and 4 inch views in the whole Storyboard. Hope this is what you needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set AutoSizing left, right, bottom, top postion based on your controls and views,[image]